# How do you remove double quotes from the image of a JavaCC token?

Tags: java, javacc

In JavaCC, I'm accepting strings that are under the condition:

```
   < STRING : "\"" ("\\" ~[] | ~["\"","\\"] )* "\"" >
```

So the image ends up printing anything that is a string but with another set of double quotes.

For example, I'll input: "This is a sentence."

And the value will result : ""This is a sentence."" stored in a String variable.

Is there a way in Java to remove the extra set of double quotes so that it only prints: **"This is a sentence."**?

Comment: What do you do with a string that extra quotes get stored? You also talk about printing - give us a [mcve] for what you get.

Comment: Where do you print the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
str = str.substring(1,str.length()-1)
```

alternate for Javacc

[Parsing Strings with JavaCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878392/parsing-strings-with-javacc)

Comment: I'm not familiar with javacc but such a curt answer lets me think you might not be either and are just answering with some basic java string manipulation. OP might not have any `str` to run java code on

Comment: Is there a way in **Java** to remove the extra set of double quotes so that it only prints: "This is a sentence."? But yes if solely using Javacc this probably isn't the answer.

Comment: No worries, I was just mentioning it probably isn't that easy. The question definitely could use some improvement, the title alone will certainly attract the kind of answer you gave.

Comment: Agreed, lets never let this kind of stuff come between our friendship again. ;)

Comment: Of course, our intercontinental friendship shall not suffer from such trivial matters !

Comment: This worked for me thank you! And idk why ppl downvoted this. I clearly asked how to do it in Java even though I was explaining the way I obtained that token from JavaCC.

Comment: I agree. It's the right answer.  I think the problem was more that the question was unclear about whether it's a Java problem or a JavaCC problem.  Anyway, the up and down votes are now at least equal.

Answer (score 2):

If the input matched by your token is `"Hello"` then the value of the `image` field of the token will be a 7 character string whose first and last characters are double quote characters.  They're not really extra they were they in the input.  Say you write

```
void foo() : {
    Token t ; }
{
    t = <STRING>
    { System.out.println( t.image ) ; }
}
```

That'll print 7 characters and then a newline.

Now if you don't want those characters, well, @Bryan's answer will do it.

```
void foo() : {
    Token t ; }
{
    t = <STRING>
    { { String nakedImage = t.image.substring(1,t.image.length()-1) ;
        System.out.println( nakedImage ) ; } }
}
```

It should be noted that no quotes are removed. `String` objects in Java are immutable, meaning they can't be changed. What really happens is that a new `String` object gets created and a reference to it is assign to the `nakedImage` variable. The `String` object that `t.image` is a reference to remains the same.

Now you still have the problem of dealing with the back slashes.  If the input is "Hello\tWorld", then `t.image` will be 14 characters long and `nakedImage` will be 12 characters long. What I do at this point is to run the string through a function builds a new string that has single characters where the `nakedImage` has escape sequences. So the result of that function on this example would be 11 characters long.

```
void foo() : {
    Token t ; }
{
    t = <STRING>
    { { String nakedImage = t.image.substring(1,t.image.length()-1) ;
        String unescapedImage = unescape( nakedImage ) ;
        System.out.println( unescapedImage ) ; } }
}
```

Here's such a function, based on one I wrote for a Java compiler.

```
private static String unescape( String str ) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer() ;
    for( int i=0, len = str.length() ; i<len ; ) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i) ;

        // Set ch and increment i ;
        if( ch == '\\' )  {
            ch = str.charAt(i+1) ;
            switch( ch ) {
                case 'b' : ch = '\b' ; i += 2 ; break ;
                case 't' : ch = '\t' ; i += 2 ; break ;
                case 'n' : ch = '\n' ; i += 2 ; break ;
                case 'f' : ch = '\f' ; i += 2 ; break ;
                case 'r' : ch = '\r' ; i += 2 ; break ;
                case '"' : case '\'' : case '\\' : i+= 2 ; break ;
                default: 
                    /*TODO Deal with errors. */ } }
        else {
            i += 1 ; }
        result.append( ch ) ; }
    return result.toString() ;
}
```